# How to import third-party framework in a custom framework (iOS7)?

Tags: xcode, ios7, import, frameworks

I'm writing a custom framework in Xcode 6.
And I need to make it support iOS7 and iOS6.
How can I import a third-party framework in my custom framework project?

I change the Deployment target to iOS 7.0 and get this warning:

> ld: warning: embedded dylibs/frameworks only run on iOS 8 or later

Or is it able to use a external third-party framework?

Comment: Does the 3rd party library you're trying to use support those older versions of iOS?

Comment: Did you got any solution?